# Query CosmosDB document using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, microsoft-azure-documentdb

I have documents stored in cosmos db, I have multiple documents for a same "stationkey"(partition key), in this example stationkey "ABC" has more than one documents with "yymm" has "2018-02" & "2018-01" e.t.c,

query that i am trying is get all "avg" & "dd" fields along with "yymm" for the given stationkey and yymm filter combination

[image: JSON Document]

I am trying to query using C#, I am trying to get "avg", "dd" & "yymm" fields from "data" array, the query that I have written is giving entire "data" array.

```
var weatherQuery = this.docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<WeatherStation>(docUri, queryOptions)
            .Where(wq => wq.stationName == stationKey && lstYearMonthFilter.Contains(wq.yearMonth))
            .Select(s => s.data);
```

what is the best way to query specific fields in from a document array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only specific fields from the array items using a double-nested anonymous class - see the altered SelectMany below. This will return yymm with every Datum, so may not be as efficient as just selecting the entire array - definitely measure the RU/s in both cases.

```
var weatherQuery = this.docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<WeatherStation>(docUri, queryOptions)
    .Where(wq => wq.stationName == stationKey && lstYearMonthFilter.Contains(wq.yearMonth))
    .SelectMany(x => x.data.Select(y => new { x.yymm, data = new[] { new { y.dd, y.avg } } }))
    .AsDocumentQuery();

var results = new List<WeatherStation>();

while (weatherQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
    results.AddRange(await weatherQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<WeatherStation>());
}

var groupedResults = results
    .GroupBy(x => x.yymm)
    .Select(x => new { x.First().yymm, data = x.SelectMany(y => y.data).ToArray() })
    .Select(x => new WeatherStation() { yymm = x.yymm, data = x.data });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jason, Do you know what is the best way to find RU/s in C# request to cosmosDB?(just like above code that you have given)

Comment: The object returned from "await weatherQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<WeatherStation>()" has a RequestCharge property on it indicating the consumed RUs. To get the total you would need to add them up from all iterations of the loop. Search for 'RequestCharge' here for more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

So you got the data in s => s.data.  To get only the avg from the array you have to do another projection as following:

```
.Select (s => s.data.Select ( a => a.avg ))
```

Modifying my answer as you say you don't find 'Select' on 'data'.

Define a class MyDocument as such:

```
public class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("dd")]
    public string dd;

    [JsonProperty("max")]
    public int max;

    [JsonProperty("min")]
    public int min;

    [JsonProperty("avg")]
    public int avg;
}

public class MyDocument : Document
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id;

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Datum[] data;
}
```

modify your code accordingly

```
IDocumentQuery<MyDocument> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDocument>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_database, _collection),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 199, MaxBufferedItemCount = 100000})
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

      while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<MyDocument> feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<MyDocument>();
            Console.WriteLine (feedResponse.Select(x => x.data.Select(y => y.avg)));
        }
```

HTH

Comment: Yes I already tried and getting an exception saying "Method 'Select' is not supported., documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.20.1 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT6.1.7601ServicePack1"

Comment: Thanks for you updated response @rafat , I have written the query in a similar way but this way of query is actually dealing with entire document (cost more RU/s on cosmos db),  what I am actually looking is to get only the required fields like "SELECT root.data.avg, root.data.dd FROM root WHERE <filter criteria>"

Comment: In that case write a query like this 

SELECT d.dd,  d.avg FROM c 
join d in c.data 
      where c.id = "ABC" 

and use "CreateDocumentQuery" to get what you want from CosmosDB.

HTH

Comment: thanks for the reply @rafat. Can we achieve the same with C#? also in this example using query vs C# which one is better ?

Comment: You write a c# code and pass this sql .. please look at createdocumentquery examples

Comment: yes I did the same it work just fine, but the question I have is instead of writing SQL can we do the same writing C# LINQ(Queryable or DocumentQuery)  not using SQL syntax?